# Mongodb find all and update all but one

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

so i have this db lookup

```
    const channelLinkId = "123456"

    location = await Locations.find({
      services: {
        $elemMatch: {
          credentials: channelLinkId,

        },
      },
    });
```

and this is what im getting back from that db look up an array of db objects.

```
[
  {
    name: "test",
    services: {
    credentials: "123456"
    }
}
  {
    name: "test1",
    services: {
    credentials: "123456"
    }
},
  {
    name: "test1",
    services: {
    credentials: "123456"
    }
  }
]
```

the result i want is to have from this db lookup is to have the second and third values of this array to have credentials empty.

```
[
  {
    name: "test",
    services: {
    credentials: "123456"
    }
}
  {
    name: "test1",
    services: {
    credentials: ""
    }
},
  {
    name: "test1",
    services: {
    credentials: ""
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: your question is not clear, show example document and expected result.

Comment: @turivishal just updated the question hopefully its more clear.

Comment: it is not possible in single query, just loop that find result and write update query for each document.

Comment: Do you have a specific criteria as to whom you want to update and who not? if so, just add that to the lookup query to only return does documents you're interested in updating.

Comment: @turivishal so im trying to do something like this `db.Locations.updateMany({}, {$set:     services: {
    credentials: ""
    }})`  so this will update all the documents i only want to update all but the first one. @ISAE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible with single update query,

- find one document using `finOne()` and select only `_id` if other fields are not required

```
const channelLinkId = "123456"
let location = await Locations.findOne({ "services.credentials": channelLinkId }, { _id: 1 });
```

- update other document's credentials that is not above found document

```
await Locations.updateMany(
  { _id: { $ne: location._id }, "services.credentials": channelLinkId },
  { $set: { "services.credentials": "" } }
);
```

Comment: wait i want to be able to update the second and third element from the first array this one will only update the first one right?

Comment: no this will update update second and third documents.